# $A(x+p)²-B(x-p)²=y$, historical/math reference

Tags: math-history, quadratics

I'm trying to build a reminder of all that I found about the quadratic function over the years. Here I came across this form of quadratic equation that I did not know:

A(x+p)²-B(x-p)²=y

I have no reference to the origin of this equation.
It is easy to move from the general form of the quadratic equation in this particular form. 
This is the first time I see this form. Does anyone know which field of mathematics or physics that has been used or is being used. Even better, a historical reference to its use, for example to solve a particular problem.